# jQuery simular un continue en un for de $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Si tengo el siguiente código

```
Arreglo.each(function() {
  if(micondicion)
    return false;
}
```

Sale del ciclo, ¿Como puedo hacer que continúe con el siguiente ?

Comment: Creo que tendrías que aclarar la razón por la cual estas usando un `return` entonces, si dentro del `each` existe una condición que haga que los demas elementos no valgan la pena iterar, pues entonces esta bien, si no es asi, no uses `return` y usa algún flag. No es obligatorio retornar algo cuando usas `each`

Answer (score 4):

Según la [documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#objectcallback) de jQuery regresar cualquier valor ***no falso*** es equivalente a hacer un `continue`, por lo que puedes regresar `true`, `1`, `"cadena"`

```
$.each(arr, function() {
    if(continuar) {
        return true; // cualquier valor no falso
    }
});
```

Para que el código sea más legible puedes colocar un `return "continue";`, la idea es que tu código indique claramente el propósito de esa línea.

Comment: *Para que el código sea más legible es conveniente añadir un comentario* te recomendaría que cambiases esa parte puesto que las ideas de clean code es que el código en si te explique qué es lo que hace y no necesites de comentarios para entenderlo. Nota: comentario **!==** documentación.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tienes un buen punto, quizá la variable de la condición podría indicar que vas a hacer un `continue`.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza `return true`;

Por ejemplo:

```
Arreglo.each(function() { 
  if(micondicion) 
    return true;
}); // Faltó cerrar función
```